# How to calculate percentage when checkboxes are checked in android?

Tags: java, android

I have a problem. I have 25 checkboxes and I need to know the percentage of how many checkboxes are checked. 
My code is below. I have an error message/force close application , when I checked the checkbox.

```
p1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (p1.isChecked()){
        palm1=longitude+","+latitude;
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), palm1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        palm1="health";
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "uncheck", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    percentage();

        }});
public void percentage(){
    Vector<CheckBox> allCheck=new Vector<CheckBox>();

    int counterChecked=0;

    allCheck.add(p1);
    allCheck.add(p2);
    allCheck.add(p3);
    allCheck.add(p4);
    allCheck.add(p5);
    allCheck.add(p6);
    allCheck.add(p7);
    allCheck.add(p8);
    allCheck.add(p9);
    allCheck.add(p10);
    allCheck.add(p11);
    allCheck.add(p12);
    allCheck.add(p13);
    allCheck.add(p14);
    allCheck.add(p15);
    allCheck.add(p16);
    allCheck.add(p17);
    allCheck.add(p18);
    allCheck.add(p19);
    allCheck.add(p20);
    allCheck.add(p21);
    allCheck.add(p22);
    allCheck.add(p23);
    allCheck.add(p24);
    allCheck.add(p25);



    for(int i=0; i<allCheck.size();i++)
           if(allCheck.get(i).isChecked()){
              // str.get(i)=longitude+","+latitude;
           counterChecked++;
           }

    double percent = (counterChecked * 100) / allCheck.size();
    persen=String.format("%.1f", percent+"%");
    kerusakan= Integer.toString(counterChecked);


}
```

Log cat:

```
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311): java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f is incompatible with java.lang.String
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.util.Formatter$Transformer.badArgumentType(Formatter.java:1452)
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.util.Formatter$Transformer.transformFromFloat(Formatter.java:1923)
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.util.Formatter$Transformer.transform(Formatter.java:1421)
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1082)
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:994)
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2254)
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2219)
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.kt.MainActivity.percentage(MainActivity.java:672)
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.kt.MainActivity$2.onCheckedChanged(MainActivity.java:121)
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:124)
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:86)
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:98)
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-02 15:27:02.280: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your logcat will tell you where it is crashing.

Comment: post your logcat too

Comment: @Buddy i was updated my log cat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out:

```
persen=String.format("%.1f", percent+"%");
```

change it to:

```
persen=String.format("%.1f", percent);
```

Comment: Changing it to `persen=String.format("%.1f %%", percent);` would be a bit better!

Comment: Right. If you desire to have an % mark after the number use the code of Prasanna. I've just removed the bug in my answer.

Comment: but, the percentage still not work, it doesnt calculate how many checkboxes are checked.

Comment: @SaSya That's an other question ;). Open up a new one and provide your results and your expected results.

Comment: @Prasanna thanks it work !! lol

Comment: @oberflansch, ya.. the other question is, how to calculate how many checboxes are checked?

Comment: @SaSya open up a new question. Try to ask questions with one probem, so one answer can solve it. You had an exception which is solved.

Comment: @oberflansch ,im so sorry.. i have edited and added my question..

Comment: @SaSya Sorry if I had not made myself clear. Basically your first qustion should be something like "how to solve the following exception: f is incompatible with java.lang.String" which was solved by my/Prasannas answer. Something like "Find out how may checkboxes are checked (in percent)" would be an other question with an other solution.